# Style a particular widget in Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

We have been using for an web app teh Jquery UI. I would like to style the dialog widget. But it has some particular things like the title thta have common styles for all the widgets. I hae used the calendar date picker also. And for example in that widget I would like the title as it is. But in the dialog I would like the title to NOT have a bg, a border etc etc...

how can I have the widgets style independently for each one?

because I know the styles are in the theme.css...but I also tried adding a new stylesheet like dialog.theme.css for example...and it isnt working for the dialog.

Comment: I think if you look farther down in the `css` you'll see the styles for each `plugin`.

Answer (score 2):

you can override the styles with a style sheet or JS if you grab the correct css class.

Example in CSS

```
.ui-button-text {
    color:red;
}
```

Example in JS

```
//All Buttons
$('.ui-button-text').css('color','red');

//Single Button
$('.selector').find('.ui-button-text').css('color','red');
```

Both examples change the color of the text for the buttons.

Now if you want multiple jQuery UI Themes, you can download each theme you want with a scope.  You can then apply multiple themes on your page

Example if you have 2 themes with scopes of *.ex1* and *.ex2*

```
<div id="#button1" class="ex1"></div>
<div id="#button2" class="ex2"></div>

$('#button1').button();
$('#button2').button();
```

This would result in button1 having your first theme and button2 having your second theme